# Not getting the expected JSON format

Tags: java, json, servlets

i am creating a JSON format for my html table. but it seems to be wrong format i am getting.

Below is My code

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Gson gson=new Gson();

    Map<Object, Object> map = null;

        try {
            con = DBConnection.createConnection();
            statement = con.createStatement();
          String sql="SELECT HOUR(BILLTIME), SUM(NETAMOUNT) FROM SYNCBILL WHERE CANCELLED='N' AND BILLDATE BETWEEN '2018-08-01' AND '2018-08-31' AND OUTLET='S0001' GROUP BY HOUR(BILLTIME);";
            ResultSet  resultSet= statement.executeQuery(sql);

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                map = new TreeMap<Object, Object>();
                String xVal = resultSet.getString("HOUR(BILLTIME)");
                String yVal = resultSet.getString("SUM(NETAMOUNT)");
                map.put(xVal, yVal);




                System.out.println(map);
            }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("SQL Issues 2...");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }}
```

I want My json Output be like

```
   [
    {
         "1": "454",
        "2": "554",
        "3": "111",
        "4": "45858",
        "5": "444",
        "6": "444",
        "7": "444",
         "8": "444",
        "9": "444",
         "10": "444"

     }
```

]

It should be enclosed in array or list in [ ] braces

but From my code i am getting result Like this

```
   {5=35942.0000}
{6=134923.3314}
{7=329324.0724}
{8=504761.6691}
{9=566401.2665}
{10=546588.2698}
{11=489917.3429}
{12=644758.5044}
{13=1108730.0100}
{14=1304635.6776}
{15=831015.3904}
{16=730210.3940}
{17=744253.6595}
{18=767145.8116}
{19=761547.2520}
{20=819265.4736}
{21=514267.8108}
{22=58592.0294}
```

I dont know Where I am doing wrong Please if any one have knowledge about this help me out

Comment: Did you not ask this question a couple of hours ago?  You don't want to create a new `Map` in every iteration of your `loop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a map outside the loop and print the map after the loop also.